# Utility for downloading artifacts from maven repo without mvn/poms

Tags: java, maven-2, repository, aether

Is there a maven client that isn't mvn (the binary included with the maven distribution) I could use to pull down an artifact from a maven repository without using a pom?  I'd like to use a maven repository as the repo for our ops team to pick up builds (including snapshots of 
builds) but I don't want them to have to mess around with writing poms and declaring dependencies in them.  Ideally, I'm looking for just a cli client that I could just pass in a repo url and coordinates and download a given artifact.  Does such a thing exist or am I better off writing a one-off script for this?

Comment: I believe this is the api whaley is referring to http://nexus.sonatype.org/nexus-faq.html#25

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Nexus. It provides a web interface that other teams can use to download artifacts. http://nexus.sonatype.org/

Comment: I was already using Nexus and I just found out about their url api for yanking down artifacts based on coordinates.  One of the nexus devs informed me of it on their irc channel yesterday.  thanks for the answer though.

Answer (score 8):

I see 3 easy options:

1. Just send them a link pointing on your artifact in your repository and have them use their browser.
2. Install and use `wget` (`wget http://path/to/artifact.extension`).
3. Install and use [`mvn dependency:get`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/get-mojo.html) (requires `mvn` but **doesn't** require a `pom.xml`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1776496/a-simple-command-line-to-download-a-remote-maven2-artifact-to-the-local-repositor/1776808#1776808) for more details).

Answer (score 3):

Use the  [maven embedder](http://maven.apache.org/embedder.html).  More to the point, use the functionality inside the maven embedder for resolving and downloading jars.  Although if you're trying to just write a simple CLI, the repository structure isn't complex and you could easily write a script that takes a maven repo url, artifact ID, group ID and version to generate the full URL to the jar.

Answer (score 1):

This is how we do it in [jcabi-aether](http://www.jcabi.com/jcabi-aether/):

```
final File repo = this.session.getLocalRepository().getBasedir();
final Collection<Artifact> deps = new Aether(this.getProject(), repo).resolve(
  new DefaultArtifact("junit", "junit-dep", "", "jar", "4.10"),
  JavaScopes.RUNTIME
);
```

All you need to provide to this lib is 1) a list of remote repositories, 2) location of a local repo, and 3) Maven coordinates of the artifact. The library uses [Apache Aether](http://www.sonatype.org/aether) from Sonatype.

Comment: can we use this plugin to download a requested artifact in to user desired location and any feature to extract it to a given location?

Answer (score 0):

Well technically the repository is accessed over HTTP, so given the repository location, artifact and coordinates, it should just be possible to give your ops team a URL to the artifact that they can hit in any browser.

Comment: That gets a little hairy with snapshots, since the actual artifact filename in the repository has a timestamp and I wanted them to be able to pull down any artifact in a programmatic fashion.  I was already using nexus and it turns out they have an api for this already.

Comment: Gotcha - good to know about nexus

Comment: @whaley can you post a link to the Nexus API?

Answer (score 0):

Think about **Pax URL** which lets you use plain URLs to reference maven artifacts like so:

```
mvn:groupId/artifactId/version
```

See [PAX URL Website](http://paxurl.ops4j.org) for more info (MVN Protocol Handler).

Toni