# A simple command line to download a remote maven2 artifact to the local repository?

Tags: maven-2

I have a library that I distribute using maven 2.  The typical user of this library doesn't use maven to build their applications, but is likely somewhat familiar with maven and probably has it installed.

I'd like to document a "simple" one line command they can use to download my library's artifacts to their local `~/.m2/repository` without requiring that they set up a pom.xml to do it.

I thought there was a way to do this, but I can't seem to find it after looking through the `install:install-file` and `dependency` plugin documentation.  I tried things like:

```
mvn install:install-file -DrepositoryId=java.net -Durl=http://download.java.net/maven/2/ -Dfile=robo-guice-0.4-20091121.174618-1.jar -DpomFile=robo-guice-0.4-20091121.174618-1.pom -DgroupId=robo-guice -DartifactId=robo-guice -Dversion=0.4-SNAPSHOT -Dpackaging=jar
```

but I think I'm barking up the wrong tree since it appears that the install plugin is used to copy locally built files into the local repository, rather than download remote artifacts into the local repository.

This is the artifact I'd like to install: http://download.java.net/maven/2/robo-guice/robo-guice/0.4-SNAPSHOT/

Is this possible using maven?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895492/how-can-i-download-a-specific-maven-artifact-in-one-command-line

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I download a specific Maven artifact in one command line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895492/how-can-i-download-a-specific-maven-artifact-in-one-command-line)

Answer (score 188, accepted):

Since version 2.1 of the [Maven Dependency Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin), there is a [dependency:get](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/get-mojo.html) goal for this purpose. To make sure you are using the right version of the plugin, you'll need to use the "fully qualified name":

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:get \
    -DrepoUrl=https://download.java.net/maven/2/ \
    -Dartifact=robo-guice:robo-guice:0.4-SNAPSHOT
```

Comment: Extra helpful for showing how to get the dependency plugin itself installed.

Comment: Pascal, can you tell me how to define user+password to reach the repository with? The trick with http://user:password@repourl did not work.

Comment: Also tried with a -DrepositoryId=something which is defined in settings.xml, dont work

Comment: the goal is nice, but how can I define the target directory where I want the file to be copyed to? (and file name)

Comment: To download the sources for this jar as well, use -Dartifact=robo-guice:robo-guice:0.4-SNAPSHOT:jar:sources

Comment: @domi (belated answer for posterity): use "-Ddest=path/to/my.jar"; otherwise, it is just copied to your local ~/.m2/repository (makes it look like nothing happened). See http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/get-mojo.html#destination =example=> mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.5.1:get 
    -DremoteRepositories=http://repo.maven.apache.org  
    -Dartifact=org.apache.ant:ant:1.8.1 
    -Ddest=ant-1.8.1.jar
(result: ant-1.8.1.jar in current directory)

Comment: How could I download from authenticated repository? I'm receiving " Not authorized , ReasonPhrase:Unauthorized." Thanks

Comment: Thanks! While, in the doc link you posted, there is `Deprecated. Use remoteRepositories` for `repoUrl`. Please update the answer maybe:)

Comment: Here's a working example of mine: `mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:get -DrepoUrl=https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/  -Dartifact=com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-support:1.10.77`

Answer (score 55):

Give them a trivial pom with these jars listed as dependencies and instructions to run:

```
mvn dependency:go-offline
```

This will pull the dependencies to the local repo.

A more direct solution is [dependency:get](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/get-mojo.html), but it's a lot of arguments to type:

```
mvn dependency:get -DrepoUrl=something -Dartifact=group:artifact:version
```

Comment: Good idea, although a command line they could copy-paste would be easier

Comment: If I could think of one I'd post it. I don't know of any plugin that does quite what's called for. I know how to write one ...

Comment: The `get` mojo actually expects `-DrepoUrl` to be present, not `-DrepositoryUrl`. Regarding the arguments to type, there is no magic, you need to provide these informations in a way or the other.

Comment: In my first scheme, the end user types only three characters: mvn. All the other typing is done by the op.

Answer (score 24):

As of version 2.4 of the [Maven Dependency Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin), you can also define a target destination for the artifact by using the -Ddest flag.  It should point to  a filename (not a directory) for the destination artifact.  See the [parameter page](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/get-mojo.html) for additional parameters that can be used

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.4:get \
    -DremoteRepositories=http://download.java.net/maven/2 \
    -Dartifact=robo-guice:robo-guice:0.4-SNAPSHOT \
    -Ddest=c:\temp\robo-guice.jar
```

Comment: Thanks! -Ddest is marked as deprecated. Is there a new solution new?

Comment: Use dependency:copy goal instead.  https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-mojo.html

Comment: the copy goal does not copy transitive deps.

Comment: -DoutputDirectory can replace -Ddest