# How can I download a specific Maven artifact in one command line?

Tags: maven-2

I can install an artifact by `install:install-file`, 
but how can I download an artifact?

For example:

```
mvn download:download-file -DgroupId=.. -DartifactId=.. -Dversion=LATEST
```

Comment: Beware that the plugin wants 'repoUrl', despite the documentation saying 'repositoryUrl'. It can drive u crazy as it did to me!

Comment: the docs (http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/get-mojo.html) shows both xml params (<repositoryUrl>...</repositoryUrl>) and command-line user-properties (mvn ... -DrepoUrl="..."). This particular example is deprecated, so no worries; now it's now uniformly remoteRepositories (in both usages); but note that parameter "destination" is user property "-Ddest=..."; e.g.=> mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.5.1:get -DremoteRepositories=repo.maven.apache.org -Dartifact=org.apache.ant:ant:1.8.1 -Ddest=ant-1.8.1.jar (result: ant-1.8.1.jar in current directory)

Answer (score 252, accepted):

In the 2020s and with recent versions of Maven (3.x), you should not need to worry about plugin version and repository URL anymore and be able to just do:

```
mvn dependency:get -Dartifact=group-id:artefact-id:version
```

---

*Original answer*

You could use the [maven dependency plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/) which has a nice [`dependency:get`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/plugin-info.html) goal since version 2.1. No need for a pom, everything happens on the command line.

To make sure to find the `dependency:get` goal, you need to explicitly tell maven to use the version 2.1, i.e. you need to use the fully qualified name of the plugin, including the version:

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:get \
    -DrepoUrl=url \
    -Dartifact=groupId:artifactId:version
```

**UPDATE:** With older versions of Maven (prior to 2.1), it is possible to run `dependency:get` normally (without using the fully qualified name and version) by forcing your copy of maven to use a given version of a plugin.

This can be done as follows:

**1. Add the following line within the `<settings>` element of your `~/.m2/settings.xml` file:**

```
<usePluginRegistry>true</usePluginRegistry>
```

**2. Add the file `~/.m2/plugin-registry.xml` with the following contents:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<pluginRegistry xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/PLUGIN_REGISTRY/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/plugin-registry-1.0.0.xsd"
xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/PLUGIN_REGISTRY/1.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
      <useVersion>2.1</useVersion>
      <rejectedVersions/>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</pluginRegistry>
```

But this doesn't seem to work anymore with maven 2.1/2.2. Actually, according to the [Introduction to the Plugin Registry](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-plugin-registry.html), features of the `plugin-registry.xml` have been redesigned (for portability) and the *plugin registry is currently in a semi-dormant state within Maven 2*. So I think we have to use the long name for now (when using the plugin without a pom, which is the idea behind `dependency:get`).

Comment: Yes, and I've just got the same resolution using dependency:get goal. 

    mvn dependency:get -Dartifact=org.apache.archiva:archiva-webapp:LATEST:war -DrepoUrl=http://repository.sonatype.org/content/repositories/central/

The only inconvenience is that I must provide a repoUrl option.

Your information really helps, I'm using mvn 2.2.1 (rdebian-1) and I didn't touch the pluginRegistry.

Thanks.

Comment: this "get" goal seems to "just work" again (no additional config/hacking required; plugin 2.5.1, mvn 3.0.4): =example=> mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.5.1:get   -DremoteRepositories=http://repo.maven.apache.org    -Dartifact=org.apache.ant:ant:1.8.1  -Ddest=ant-1.8.1.jar

Comment: What's the difference between get and install? Don't they both fetch to your local maven repo? --edit: wait, no, I get it now; install is for *your* local deps to be copied to the local m2 repo, get fetches them from a remote.

Comment: how to also get the sources jar for the specific artifact w/o pom?

Comment: found it, just append `:jar:sources` to the **artifact**, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/31109185/537554

Comment: With newer versions of Maven (e.g. 3.6.0) you may still do it with just `mvn dependency:get -Dartifact=group-id:artefact-id:version`

Comment: To which folder does it download the jar?

Comment: @Dims, you're correct. Doesn't work with Maven 3.6.3

Comment: Is there a way to output the file path to artifact jar?

Comment: In newer versions `-DrepoUrl` has been replaced by `-DremoteRepositories`

Comment: if there are mirrors setting in `settings.xml`, check there is no mirror for repo id `temp`.

Answer (score 123):

With the latest version (2.8) of the [Maven Dependency Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/usage.html), downloading an artifact from the Maven Central Repository is as simple as:

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:get -Dartifact=groupId:artifactId:version[:packaging[:classifier]]
```

where `groupId:artifactId:version`, etc. are the [Maven coordinates](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Maven_Coordinates)

An example, tested with Maven 2.0.9, Maven 2.2.1, and Maven 3.0.4:

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:get -Dartifact=org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:3.4.0.GA:jar:sources
```

(Thanks to Pascal Thivent for providing his [wonderful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1896110/238421) in the first place. I am adding another answer, because it wouldn't fit in a comment and it would be too extensive for an edit.)

Comment: I used this to download maven archetype. This works great if you are behind proxy and working with eclipse which fails to register to identify maven archtypes even though you have configured proxy in settings xml.

Comment: mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:get -Dartifact=org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp:1.0:jar

Comment: Can you explain what `jar:sources` means/does? why do you need to specify "jar"? and does "sources" mean it will download additional dependencies the artifact requires?

Comment: "jar" is the packaging type, "sources" is the classifier. Given one dependency (for example, [hibernate-core](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/5.4.8.Final/)), there could be more than one artifact. Often, there are: 1. the binary-only library, 2. `sources`, a JAR file containing only Java sources, 3. `javadoc`, a JAR file with API docs only. See also: [Maven Default Artifact Handlers](http://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/artifact-handlers.html).

Comment: Thanks about clarifying how to use the `[:classifier]` correctly, if I have a assemlby plugin created zip file that I want to download.

Comment: This worked as of Maven version 3.6.3.

Answer (score 64):

Here's what worked for me to download the latest version of an artifact called "component.jar" with Maven 3.1.1 in the end (other suggestions did not, mostly due to maven version changes I believe)

This actually downloads the file and copies it into the local working directory

From bash:

```
mvn dependency:get \
    -DrepoUrl=http://.../ \
        -Dartifact=com.foo.something:component:LATEST:jar \
        -Dtransitive=false \
        -Ddest=component.jar \
```

Comment: Great, thanks! I didn't event need the `-DrepoUrl`, I guess it was implied from my pom anyway. Also I didn't use `-Ddest` as I actually *did* want to it download to the regular `.m2` directory.

Comment: The `dest` parameter [is deprecated](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/get-mojo.html#destination), and can be replaced with an invokation of [`copy`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-mojo.html) after `get` like so: `mvn dependency:copy -Dartifact=com.foo.something:component:LATEST:jar -DoutputDirectory=.` (in this case placing the jar in the working directory).

Comment: @JacobRaihle Then I cannot download file without pom.xml, getting the following error: `Goal requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory`.

Comment: @Athlan No-pom support may be a newer feature, I suppose. Nowadays I can just run `mvn dependency:copy` (without `dependency:get` first).

Comment: instead of dest parameter; i specify an alternate local repo path. this gives me all the transitive dependencies in a single place. e.g.:  ´ mvn -Dmaven.repo.local=./temp_repo org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:get -Dartifact=com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:2.5.0 ´

Comment: It looks like `dependency:copy` also downloads it first, so using `dependency:get` to download explicitly is redundant. I first tried `copy` with the file already in local repo and then again after removing it from local repo and could clearly see that it got downloaded again.

Answer (score 37):

Regarding how to get the artifact binary, [Pascal Thivent's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1896110/537554) is it, but to also get the artifact sources jar, we can use:

```
mvn dependency:get -Dartifact=groupId:artifactId:version:jar:sources
```

e.g.

```
mvn dependency:get -Dartifact=junit:junit:4.12:jar:sources
```

This works because the [`artifact`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/get-mojo.html#artifact) parameter actually consists of `groupId:artifactId:version[:packaging][:classifier]`. Just the **packaging** and **classifier** are optional.

With `jar` as **packaging** and `sources` as **classifier**, the maven dependency plugin understands we're asking for the sources jar, not the artifact jar.

Unfortunately for now sources jar files cannot be downloaded transitively, which does make sense, but ideally I do believe it can also respect the option `downloadSources` just like the maven eclipse plugin does.

Comment: This works for me on mvn 3.9.1, however because I'm running in powershell I needed to quote my artifact like this ... -Dartifact="org.testng:testng:7.7.1"  

Otherwise I get [ERROR] Error resolving version for plugin '.testng:testng'

Answer (score 23):

One could use dependency:copy (http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-mojo.html) which takes a list of artifacts defined in the plugin configuration section and copies them to a specified location, renaming them or stripping the version if desired. This goal can resolve the artifacts from remote repositories if they don't exist in either the local repository or the reactor.

Not all the properties of the plugin could be used in maven CLI. The properties which have "User Property:" property defined could be specified. In the below example I am downloading junit to my temp folder and stripping the vesion from the jar file.

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:copy -Dartifact=junit:junit:4.11 -DoutputDirectory=/tmp -Dmdep.stripVersion=true
```

where
    artifact=junit:junit:4.11 is the maven coordinates. And you specify artifcat as groupId:artifactId:version[:packaging[:classifier]]

(Thanks to Pascal Thivent for providing his https://stackoverflow.com/a/18632876/2509415 in the first place. I am adding another answer)

Answer (score 12):

The usage from the official documentation:

```
https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/usage.html#dependency:get
```

For my case, see the answer below:

```
mvn dependency:get -Dartifact=$2:$3:$4:$5 -DremoteRepositories=$1 -Dtransitive=false
mvn dependency:copy -Dartifact=$2:$3:$4:$5 -DremoteRepositories=$1 -Dtransitive=false -DoutputDirectory=$6

#mvn dependency:get -Dartifact=com.huya.mtp:hynswup:1.0.88-SNAPSHOT:jar -DremoteRepositories=http://nexus.google.com:8081/repository/maven-snapshots/ -Dtransitive=false
#mvn dependency:copy -Dartifact=com.huya.mtp:hynswup:1.0.88-SNAPSHOT:jar -DremoteRepositories=http://nexus.google.com:8081/repository/maven-snapshots/ -Dtransitive=false -DoutputDirectory=.
```

Use the command `mvn dependency:get` to download the specific artifact and use
the command `mvn dependency:copy` to copy the downloaded artifact to the destination directory `-DoutputDirectory`.

Answer (score 9):

one liner to download latest maven artifact without mvn:

```
curl -O -J -L  "https://repository.sonatype.org/service/local/artifact/maven/content?r=central-proxy&g=io.staticcdn.sdk&a=staticcdn-sdk-standalone-optimizer&e=zip&v=LATEST"
```

Comment: Downvoted. This solution only seems to work with a specific repository product.

Comment: Worked great with Nexus 2.x, doesn't work with 3.x (yet)

Comment: curl: option -J is unknown

Comment: If you add the credentials to the URL, it makes it insecure.

Answer (score 7):

**maven command:**
if you use maven, you can use `dependency:copy` to download the artifact to the local folder.

```
mvn dependency:copy -Dartifact=groupId:artifactId:version[:packaging[:classifier]] -DoutputDirectory=<your local path>. -U
```

Refer: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-mojo.html

**Curl command:**

```
# guide: https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/rest-and-integration-api/search-api

# https://msnexus.xxxx.com/service/rest/v1/search/assets?sort=version&repository=public&maven.groupId=<groupId>&maven.artifactId=<>&maven.baseVersion=1.46.0-SNAPSHOT&maven.extension=war

download_artifact() {
    local host_url=$1
    local group_id=$2
    local artifact_id=$3
    local artifact_type=$4
    local artifact_version=$5
    local final_name=$6
    local location=$7

    local search_version=$5
    local prerelease="false"
    if [[ "${artifact_version}" == *"SNAPSHOT" ]]; then
        prerelease="true"
    fi
    if [[ "${artifact_version}" == "latest"* ]]; then
        search_version="*"
    fi
    assets_url="${host_url}/service/rest/v1/search/assets?sort=version&repository=public&maven.groupId=${group_id}&maven.artifactId=${artifact_id}&maven.baseVersion=${search_version}&prerelease=${prerelease}&maven.extension=${artifact_type}"

    echo "INFO: Assets url: $assets_url"

    download_url=$(curl "$assets_url" -H "accept: application/json" | jq -r ".items[0].downloadUrl // empty")

    echo "INFO: Downloading artifact from url: $download_url"

    if [[ -z "$download_url" ]]; then
        echo "ERROR: Artifact not exists in Nexus, please check your version [${version}] for [${service_name}]"
        exit 1
    fi

    pre_dir=$(pwd)

    if [[ ! -d "$location" ]]; then
        mkdir -p $location
    fi

    cd $location

    curl -o "${final_name}.${artifact_type}" "$download_url"

    cd $pre_dir
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also do this using docker in PowerShell:

```
docker run -it --rm -v ${PWD}:/build/source -v ${HOME}/.m2:/build/.m2 --net=host aemdesign/centos-java-buildpack:jdk8 /bin/bash --login -c 'mvn dependency:get -Dmaven.repo.local=/build/.m2/repository -DrepoUrl=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2 -Dartifact=io.prometheus.jmx:jmx_prometheus_javaagent:LATEST -Ddest=/build/source/jmx_prometheus_javaagent.jar'
```

or in bash:

```
docker run -it --rm -v $PWD:/build/source -v $HOME/.m2:/build/.m2 --net=host aemdesign/centos-java-buildpack:jdk8 /bin/bash --login -c 'mvn dependency:get -Dmaven.repo.local=/build/.m2/repository -DrepoUrl=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2 -Dartifact=io.prometheus.jmx:jmx_prometheus_javaagent:LATEST -Ddest=/build/source/jmx_prometheus_javaagent.jar'
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example to get ASM-7 using Maven 3.6:

```
mvn dependency:get -DremoteRepositories=maven.apache.org -Dartifact=org.ow2.asm:7.0:sources:jar
```

Or you can download the jar from here: https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:org.ow2.asm%20AND%20a:asm and then

```
mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=org.ow2.asm -DartifactId=asm -Dversion=7.0 -Dclassifier=sources -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/asm-7.0.jar
```

Answer (score 2):

To copy artifact in specified location use `copy` instead of get.

```sh
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.2:copy \
  -DrepoUrl=someRepositoryUrl \
  -Dartifact="com.acme:foo:RELEASE:jar" -Dmdep.stripVersion -DoutputDirectory=/tmp/
```

Answer (score 0):

The command:

```
mvn install:install-file
```

Typically [installs](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/usage.html) the artifact in your local repository, so you shouldn't need to download it. However, if you want to share your artifact with others, you will need to deploy the artifact to a central repository see the [deploy plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/usage.html) for more details.

Additionally adding a [dependency](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/howto.html) to your POM will automatically fetch any third-party artifacts you need when you build your project. I.e. This will download the artifact from the central repository.

Answer (score 0):

`LATEST` is deprecated, try with range `[,)`

```
./mvnw org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.1:get \  
-DremoteRepositories=repoId::default::https://nexus/repository/maven-releases/ \
"-Dartifact=com.acme:foo:[,)"
```

Comment: Have you tried it? This will not work: *maven-dependency-plugin:get*  do NOT support version ranges.
Way I made version rages work was like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/73801763/603314

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately *maven-dependency-plugin:get* do NOT support version ranges e.g. [2.17.1,)  or [,)

If you need download a specific maven artifact but using **version range**, as I do, look here:

[Download Maven artifact with version range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73801762/download-maven-artifact-with-version-range/73801763#73801763)