# Make groovy script grab a jar off the filesystem like grape

Tags: groovy, jar, groovy-grape

Grape seems to work fairly well for adding jars to your classpath.  It
also does a lot of other things such as fetching and dependency management.
e.g.

```
#!/home/robert/bin/groovy

import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils

@Grab(group='commons-lang', module='commons-lang', version='2.4')

def strings = ['Hello', 'Groovy', 'AVeryLongWord!', 'A simple sentence']
strings.each { String aString ->
    println "$aString: ${StringUtils.abbreviate(aString,10)}"
}
```

Unfortunately if there is a jar on my filesystem that I want to
dynamically add to the filesystem then I have to resort to a much
uglier solution.

```
#!/home/robert/bin/groovy

def loader = this.class.classLoader.rootLoader
loader.addURL(new File("/home/robert/somejars/arithmetic-1.1.jar").toURI().toURL())

// can't use traditional package import
arithmeticMainClass = Class.forName("org.scharp.arithmetic.Main")

println "42 - 23 = " + arithmeticMainClass.subtract(42, 23)

// can't use "new" operator
myArithmeticObject = arithmeticMainClass.newInstance()
```

Is there a way to make grape grab a jar from the filesystem?  If not,
can I somehow replicate what grape is doing in groovy/java?

I would like this solution to work for scripts that can be run by many users and many incompatible jars so adding jars to a common directory such as ~/.groovy/lib/ won't work.

I could create a local maven repository for local, jar libaries but
that seems like overkill.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's been [some interest in adding this feature to grape](http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/Adding-jar-files-to-the-classpath-td3301287.html) but nothing serious.  My guess is that it's unlikely that this will be added in the near future. (6-18 months)

Answer (score 7):

This is how I solved this.
When Grape (Ivy) wants something it caches it under the `~/.groovy/grapes` directory. All you need to do is just create your own ivy.xml file and throw your jar in there. I figured it out by just looking at some of the other artifacts donwloaded from maven. Here is a small example.....

We use Oracle here and I wanted it's jdbc jar file to be able to be 'Grabbed' by my Groovy scripts.
Unfortunately, I could not find any repository that had this jar on the web.

- Step 1 : create directory `~/.groovy/grapes/com.oracle`
- Step 2 : create directory `~/.groovy/grapes/com.oracle/ojdbc6`
- Step 3 : create directory `~/.groovy/grapes/com.oracle/ojdbc6/jars`
- Step 4 : Get a copy of Oracle's ojdbc jar file and rename it. Our oracle version is 11.2.0.1.0 and we use Java6 so I got the locally installed ojdbc6.jar file and copied as ojdbc6-11.2.0.1.0.jar. This file I put into the directory created in the prior step.
- Step 5 : create an ivy-11.2.0.1.0.xml config file.This file should be put into the directory created in step 2. For this step I heavily relied on examples from other artifacts grabbed. Any apache commons lib is a good example.

Here is my xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ivy-module version="2.0" xmlns:m="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/maven"
>
  <info organisation="com.oracle" module="ojdbc6" revision="11.2.0.1.0" status="release" publication="20130102153401">
    <license name="" />
    <description homepage="">Oracle ojdbc driver</description>
  </info>
  <configurations>
    <conf name="default" visibility="public" description="" extends="runtime,master" />
    <conf name="master" visibility="public" description="" />
    <conf name="compile" visibility="public" description="" />
    <conf name="provided" visibility="public" description="" />
    <conf name="runtime" visibility="public" description="" extends="compile" />
    <conf name="test" visibility="public" description="" extends="runtime" />
    <conf name="system" visibility="public" description="" />
    <conf name="sources" visibility="public" description="" />
    <conf name="javadoc" visibility="public" description="" />
    <conf name="optional" visibility="public" description="" />
  </configurations>
  <publications>
    <artifact name="ojdbc6" type="jar" ext="jar" conf="master" />
  </publications>
</ivy-module>
```

Now I can use this jar in my groovy scripts with the following....

```
@Grapes([
  @GrabConfig(systemClassLoader=true),
  @Grab('com.oracle:ojdbc6:11.2.0.1.0'),
])
import groovy.sql.*
```

To make things easy for deploying this grape to multiple servers I created a zip file that I could extract anywhere....

```
$ unzip -qql oracle_jdbc_groovy_grape.zip
        0  06-11-2012 13:50   .groovy/grapes/com.oracle/
        0  06-12-2012 14:17   .groovy/grapes/com.oracle/ojdbc6/
        0  06-12-2012 14:17   .groovy/grapes/com.oracle/ojdbc6/jars/
  2111220  06-11-2012 11:46   .groovy/grapes/com.oracle/ojdbc6/jars/ojdbc6-11.2.0.1.0.jar
     2349  06-11-2012 11:50   .groovy/grapes/com.oracle/ojdbc6/ivy-11.2.0.1.0.xml
```

Answer (score 4):

You can [customize the ivy settings](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Grape#Grape-CustomizeIvysettings) that Grape uses by creating a `~/.groovy/grapeConfig.xml` file.

Here's an example how to use the local file system as repository:

```
<ibiblio name="local" root="file:${user.home}/.m2/repository/" m2compatible="true"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I mentioned that I didn't want to make a local maven repository--I'd like to be able to specify any jar on the filesystem.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize that. From the [source code](https://svn.codehaus.org/groovy/trunk/groovy/modules/grape-ivy/) it looks like Grape is fully built on top of Ivy. You'd probably have to implement your own AST transformation to make this work.

Comment: Thank's for the source link but I can't figure it out :(  It's too bad, it seems grape can run (download and load an ivy jar) but not walk (load a jar from the filesystem)

Answer (score 0):

According to [this enhancement](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-4223), Grapes will now also search your local Maven repo, along with Maven Central.

You can install any jar(s) in your local repo by:

- running `mvn install` in your project
- using `mvn dependecy:get`; see [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/get-mojo.html) and [example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1895492/3124333)
- using `mvn install:install-file`; see [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/install-file-mojo.html) and [example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4955635/3124333)