# General Maven pull from repo without doing a build from SVN

Tags: maven

I have wars that I have already built, and for some process, I'd like to have maven just go grab a particular version from my repo (Nexus), and then i'll have jenkins do some stuff with it.
Is this possible, to not have maven pull that source from svn, but only get a particular version of a war from the repo?

Comment: Of course that's possible.  Fetching dependencies, aka artifacts such as your war, from nexus is maven's main job. The part about jenkins doing somethign with it is wierd though.  Can you edit your question to describe what your use case it?

Comment: i use jenkins call maven, sort of just a wrapper around maven. i want to make a jenkins job that does not pull any code from svn, i want jenkins to call maven to have maven get a specific version of a war that is already in the repo. i want to be able to go back to any version that is in the repo

Comment: what do you want to do with it?

Comment: i want to then move the war to another location, i'll use a command shell to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think similar question has been already asked, see: [How can I download a specific Maven artifact in one command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895492/how-can-i-download-a-specific-maven-artifact-in-one-command-line)

Maven dependency plugin should do the job for you.