# How download maven artifact from remote repository to local folder?

Tags: java, maven, dependency-management

I am writing a script for deploying java application. The scenarion is simple:

1. Download pusblished application (jar) from repository to local folder.
2. Run java with jar

How can I download this jar from maven repo to local folder?

**Important**

1. The question is **not** about resolving one artifact. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895492/how-can-i-download-a-specific-maven-artifact-in-one-command-line) is a solution to donwload single artifact to local repository, but I want to specified folder.
2. Also the solution should work from command line **without** pom file. E.g. run `mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:copy` will fail, because it runs only in folder where `pom.xml` is present.

Comment: It's usually possible to grab jar files individually at [Maven Repository](http://mvnrepository.com/). Note that you'll have to manually track dependencies your way (yuck). If you have a pom file, you could could let maven populate your `.m2` folder

Comment: you can use curl utility to download individual files from maven repo.   example `curl http://central.maven.org/maven2/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.2/commons-logging-1.2.jar >> commons-logging.jar`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try `dependency:get` like this:

```
mvn dependency:get -DrepoUrl=http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/ -Dartifact=org.springframework:spring-context:4.0.4.RELEASE:jar -Dtransitive=false -Ddest=spring-context-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar
```

Comment: Do you know a minimal version or dependecy plugin? I have tried this with version 2.1 and it did not work. But with version 2.9 it works :)