# How to cache specific maven artifact into local repository?

Tags: maven, repository

Suppose I have some Maven coordinates, like

`org.ow2.asm:asm:5.0.3`

How would I cache these artifact into (existing) local maven repository?

Comment: Using this dependency and building it shall cache this on `.m2/repository/` on your local. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: Yes, but which command? Not very fluent with maven...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your pom.xml add under `<dependencies>` the following :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
    <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

and use the command

```
mvn clean verify
```

at your project level to build the project and its dependencies to find the artifact in the corresponding `.m2/repository` folder.

Comment: Is it possible not to create `pom.xml`?

Comment: Using maven you must be having one already to define a project.

Comment: @Naman I do not use Maven as build tool, but do use Maven repository, so there is no `pom.xml` in my project.

Comment: @Pavlus In such a case, you can include the dependency using the build framework of yours e.g. `build.gradle` file for gradle as well. The question was tagged with [tag:maven], hence the answer to include the dependency in pom.xml.

Comment: @Naman well, I included this dependency in `build.gradle` and it ended up in gradle cache, and not in local Maven repository, I believe, commentaries about *command* and "is it possible not to create pom.xml" was because one want to cache it in local repo, by explicitly running command to do that and without creating Maven project.

Comment: @Pavlus The answer to that was considering that the maven framework in use would need you to anyway have a `pom.xml`. I am not sure how gradle caches the dependencies, but as far as `maven` is concerned it would download the artifact from the repository specified and cached it in `.m2` which is where it would lookup for the artifact the next time unless forced to download the artifact from global repository again. If you want to cache it in a local repository, there has to be some configuration to drive that. Unless you just download a jar and move it to the folder manually.

Answer (score 3):

I believe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1896110/950189) *truly* answers your question: it shows how to download and cache locally a specific Maven artifact from specific Maven repository with all dependencies **without** having to create `pom.xml` or any other sort of dependency declaration.