# download artifacts from artifactory using Maven

Tags: maven, bamboo

I have artifacts in artifactory and I would like to download using maven. Could you please advise on how to download the artifacts from artifactory using specific build number?

Comment: What do you mean by "build number"? Is your build number a part of the version number? In Maven, you address artifacts by groupId, artifactId and version (and, sometimes, additional infos).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I download a specific Maven artifact in one command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895492/how-can-i-download-a-specific-maven-artifact-in-one-command-line)