# Download Maven artifact with version range

Tags: maven, maven-3, artifactory, nexus, artifact

I need download specific Maven artifact using version range e.g.:
GroupId:`org.apache.logging.log4j`
ArtifactId=`log4j-api`
Version=`[2.17.1,)`

Right now I need it in one CI job.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was hoping to find an easier solution, but at least this works:

Create `pom.xml` file

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>cz.vondr</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-download</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>

    <properties>
        <dep.group>org.apache.commons</dep.group>
        <dep.artifact>commons-lang3</dep.artifact>
        <dep.version>3.12.0</dep.version>
        <dep.type>jar</dep.type>
        <dep.classifier></dep.classifier>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${dep.group}</groupId>
            <artifactId>${dep.artifact}</artifactId>
            <version>${dep.version}</version>
            <type>${dep.type}</type>
            <classifier>${dep.classifier}</classifier>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

And then use it to download artifact using command:
`mvn dependency:copy-dependencies "-DoutputDirectory=./downloaded-dependencies" -Ddep.group="org.apache.logging.log4j" -Ddep.artifact="log4j-api" -Ddep.version="[2.17.1,)"`

#### Additional information

Basic description is here:
http://vondrnotes.blogspot.com/2022/09/download-maven-artifact-with-version.html
Working example is here:
https://github.com/bugs84/download-maven-dependency-with-version-range