# At download Maven incorrectly resolves a transitive AAR dependency as JAR and fails to fetch it

Tags: maven, aar

I'm trying to use a Maven project to download some Android dependencies (I don't want to use Gradle because it generates directories with hash values, which makes it hard to locate files). I've configured several dependency libraries, and most of them can be downloaded to the local repository successfully. However, I encountered an issue when configuring the following dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>android.arch.persistence.room</groupId>
    <artifactId>runtime</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
    <type>aar</type>
</dependency>
```

This dependency has a transitive dependency on another AAR library (com.android.support:support-core-utils:jar:26.1.0), but Maven incorrectly identifies it as a JAR, causing the download to fail.

I attempted to use dependencyManagement to specify the type, but it had no effect:

```xml
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.android.support</groupId>
            <artifactId>support-core-utils</artifactId>
            <type>aar</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Is there a way to make Maven correctly recognize indirect AAR dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, for your scenario I would neither use [Apache Maven](https://maven.apache.org/what-is-maven.html). You're trying to solve a typical task for a transitive package manager with a fully-fledged project build tool, whose integrated dependency manager is just one tool of many and is not really supposed to be used standalone. Just take a look at this [Stackoverflow Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895492/how-can-i-download-a-specific-maven-artifact-in-one-command-line) to see the cramp.

There's an alternative to Maven except of Gradle. For build tasks one can also use the combination of [Apache Ant](https://ant.apache.org/) as a build automation tool, and [**Apache Ivy**](https://ant.apache.org/ivy/features.html) as a dependency manager. Ivy is very flexible and you can solve any dependency related task you need to. And -- you can use it [standalone](https://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/2.5.2/standalone.html).

So, the following steps will download `android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.1` with all its transitive dependencies, incl. `com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.1.0` -- latter correctly as an `.aar` file.

1. [Download Ivy](https://ant.apache.org/ivy/download.cgi), extract the archive and copy the `.jar` file wherever you need. Or install Ivy, if available with your system's package manager.
2. Lets define WHAT you want to retrieve. Write a -- for your needs very simple -- [Ivy Module Descriptor File](https://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/2.5.2/ivyfile.html), shortly "Ivy File". Usually it is named `ivy.xml`. As you see, it describes the packages you're interested in. If you need more of them, just add another `<dependency>`. Transitive dependencies will be downloaded automatically.

```
<ivy-module version='2.0'>
    <info organisation='org.apache' module='ivy'/>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency org='android.arch.persistence.room' name='runtime' rev='1.1.1'/>
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

3. Next we define WHERE to get the package. Write an [Ivy Settings File](https://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/2.5.2/settings.html). Except of the Central Maven Repo also Google's Maven Repo was configured as a fallback.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<ivysettings>
    <settings defaultResolver='maven' />
    <resolvers>
        <chain name='maven'>
            <ibiblio name='Repository repo1.maven.org' m2compatible='true' root='https://repo1.maven.org/maven2' />
            <ibiblio name='Repository maven.google.com' m2compatible='true' root='https://maven.google.com' />
        </chain>
    </resolvers>
</ivysettings>
```

4. Invoke Ivy. Insert proper paths as you need. The result will be put to `target_dir`. If you skip the option `-cache`, the downloaded packages will be stored in the default local repository `$HOME/.ivy2/cache/`.

```
java -jar <path>/ivy-2.5.2.jar -ivy <path>/ivy.xml -settings <path>/ivysettings.xml -cache <target_dir>
```

If you take a look into the result, e.g. with `tree <target_dir>`, you'll find inter alia the file you missed:

```
<target_dir>/com.android.support/support-core-utils/aars/support-core-utils-26.1.0.aar
```

That's it.

---

P.S.: In case you don't like e.g. the structure of the output subdirectories, or whatever -- you can configure anything to be as you want