# Use androidx libraries in my non Android Studio setup: No Build System, only using android sdk

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, compilation, androidx

I'm trying to use Androidx Libraries for my App. Since I don't use Android Studio because of a low spec Laptop. My ultimate goal is to learn, So I don't like using any build system. I just setup my own simple scripts for compiling my apps. So far, I'm successful. I use Vscodium and use android sdk libraries. I also have an emulator already setup. I like my setup, it's smooth, not lagging like android studio. Here's my simple script for building the app

```
#!/bin/bash
rm app.apk app.apk.idsig MainActivity.jar classes.dex
cd R/com/example/helloworld
rm R.class R.java 'R$layout.class'
cd ../../../../
~/Android/build-tools/34.0.0/aapt2 compile layout/MainUI.xml -o layout
~/Android/build-tools/34.0.0/aapt2 link layout/layout_MainUI.xml.flat  -o app.apk  -I ~/Android/platforms/android-34/android.jar --manifest AndroidManifest.xml  --java R
cd R/com/example/helloworld
javac R.java
cd ../../../../
kotlinc -classpath /home/mousin/Android/platforms/android-34/android.jar:/home/mousin/Downloads/app/R MainActivity.kt -d MainActivity.jar
~/Android/build-tools/34.0.0/d8 MainActivity.jar
~/Android/build-tools/34.0.0/aapt add app.apk classes.dex
echo "5949147123" |  ~/Android/build-tools/34.0.0/apksigner sign --ks mousin.keystore app.apk
adb install app.apk
```

This might help understand the level I'm at. I keep it changing according to my needs.
My problem is that I want to use new features from androidx. I have the aar and source files, but I don't know how exactly to use them.
**Problem 1**: Not knowing how to fix xml dependencies like theme names Theme.Appcompat
**Problem 2**: Even if I somehow find all the classes from every .aar file, my file compiles, no errors, there are runtime errors.
In short: Help me resolving dependencies manually from .aar or .jar files from the Google Maven Repo without Build systems

**So far tried**
Tried extending my MainActivity class from AppCompatActivity, I collected every android library that my imports depend upon from the official website Google Maven repo. The file compiles successfully but gives runtime errors like class not found Exception.
About xml files: I tried finding the parent xml files from the res folders of these libraries, so that I could write their code and then compile using aapt2 tool, but I couldn't find the code.
A little help to resolve dependencies from android libraries please...

Comment: You really like to live your life the hard way. Note that androidx is not one libraries but a set of ~100 libraries which have a dependecies among each other. So without build system you have to manually resolve all of those dependencies manually download the libraries and integrate them into your manual build process. IMHO you should better get yourself a PC suitable for development.

Comment: @Robert -- Not everyone can afford a new PC just like that, not only in the world's low income regions.

Comment: @Mousin -- You might want to take a look on the sleek yet powerful dependency manager [Apache Ivy](https://ant.apache.org/ivy/). I provided a basic usage example in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77234177/19980636).

Comment: If your PC is powerful enough to run an emulated Android device then it has enough power to use Gradle build system to compile Android apps. It may just take a few seconds to compile and build everything. This would allow you to develop Android apps the regular way just without Android Studio as UI.

Comment: @Robert -- Fair argument.