# Download jar from a repository using maven without pom

Tags: maven

I see a couple questions like [How can I download a specific Maven artifact in one command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895492/how-can-i-download-a-specific-maven-artifact-in-one-command-line) but the answers look outdated. How can I download JAR files to a certain directory from a repository I provide on the command line using mvn with no pom in 2023? I don't see how I would tell [dependency:copy](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-mojo.html) to use a certain repository.

I call `get` and don't see my jar files.

```
mvn -U -e -X dependency:get -Dartifact=net.sourceforge.jmarcos00:jtds:1.3.3:jar -DremoteRepositories=clojars.org -DoutputDirectory=D:/jars/
```

I read, a call to `get` may be followed by `copy`, which I call like

```
mvn -U -e -X dependency:copy -Dartifact=net.sourceforge.jmarcos00:jtds:1.3.3:jar -DremoteRepositories=clojars.org -DoutputDirectory=D:/jars/
```

This results in an error `Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: Could not find artifact net.sourceforge.jmarcos00:jtds:jar:1.3.3 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)`

I'm in an Adobe ColdFusion environment and need additional functionalities so I want to put JAR files and their dependencies in my classpath, eventually. I though maven is the way to go.

Comment: If you like to add other jar's to your classpath define them as dependencies? (scope: runtime?) ?