# How to simply download a JAR using Maven?

Tags: maven, jar

How do I download JAR during a build in Maven script?

Comment: Download to where? With or without a POM? See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1776496/a-simple-command-line-to-download-a-remote-maven2-artifact-to-the-local-reposito

Answer (score 87):

Maven does not work like that. Here's the closest you'll get to my knowledge:

```
mvn dependency:get -DremoteRepositories=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ \
                   -DgroupId=junit -DartifactId=junit -Dversion=4.8.2 \
                   -Dtransitive=false
```

Note that all parameters except transitive are required.
Also note that Maven will download the jar to your local repository, and there's no sensible way (that I know of) to copy it to a local directory.

**Reference:**

- [`dependency:get`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/get-mojo.html)

Comment: @chrispolzer it does in Maven Dependency Plugin 2.8, while outputting a warning message regarding deprecation. It no longer works in current versions (3.1.1).

Comment: It worked for me using MobaXterm on Windows too.

Comment: `mvn dependency:copy`  should be used instead of deprecated get

Answer (score 67):

Or since 3.1, simply as
`mvn dependency:get -Dartifact=org.springframework:spring-instrument:3.2.3.RELEASE`

Comment: For those like me who don't know Maven but are forced to use it: it downloads the jars in `~/.m2/repository/<artifact...>`.

Comment: It works, but I had to put "" around the package like -Dartfiact="groupId:artifactId:version". Was using powershell.

Answer (score 33):

Note: This answer is for `downloading the jars directly from maven without any scripts` [That is how Google directed me here]

Assuming `mvn` dependency is like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
    <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.7</version>
</dependency>
```

Goto http://search.maven.org and search for `g:"com.zaxxer" AND a:"HikariCP" AND v:"2.4.7"` (simply searching for `HikariCP` also works. You may need to select the appropriate `GroupId` and `Version` from the results)

In the `Search Results -> Download` column, you should see `jar  javadoc.jar  sources.jar` available for direct download

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with maven and therefore does not answer OP's question.

Answer (score 25):

You can use:

```
mvn dependency:copy \
  -Dartifact=<group>:<artifact-name>:<version> \
  -DoutputDirectory=/tmp/my_custom_dir
```

(Replace `<values>` with the ones of your case)

That's the full documentation of the goal: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-mojo.html

Note: the other "dependecy:get" way of doing this has been deprecated.

Answer (score 15):

This is what I do (2022 answer), go to https://mvnrepository.com/, search for your .jar and click on here:
[image]

Comment: IMHO this does not answer the original question, because the question was **to use Maven** to download the JARs, not how to download it manually.

Comment: ... answered my question, thanks.

Answer (score 10):

You can download Jar package to specific directory.

```
mvn dependency:get -Dartifact=org.riversun:random-forest-codegen:1.0.0 -Ddest=./
```

Comment: dest is deprecated. This can be done in two commands: mvn dependency:get -Dartifact=org.riversun:random-forest-codegen:1.0.0:0.8.5:jar:nodeps
mvn dependency:copy -Dartifact=org.riversun:random-forest-codegen:1.0.0:jar:nodeps -DoutputDirectory=.

Answer (score 8):

See [How to use Maven pom to download jar files only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7742252/how-to-use-maven-pom-to-download-jar-files-only). This worked really nicely for me.

My use case was that I wanted to download some of the dependency jars to deploy to a QA server, and was doing it manually (outside of the Maven build).  I'm not sure exactly what your use case is.

Answer (score 6):

Normally you don't use Maven for "just downloading", but for your build process. So normally, you do the following steps:

1. Define a new project by defining the archetype of your project and some needed properties.
2. Define as a dependency the library you want to use.
3. Run Maven with `mvn compile`

As a side effect, you will have downloaded the library to your local Maven repository. There are a lot of plugins to do something with dependencies, so have e.g. a look at the [Maven Dependency plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/).

Comment: Define "normally" in a jenkins pipeline step where you just need to download and deploy a jar :)

Answer (score 5):

If you just want to download a JAR once from a maven mirror I suggest you could just do this manually:

For Maven 1:
http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven/

For Maven 2:
http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/

These are the repositories (a mirror anyway) that maven will get its JARs from - you can easily access them in the webbrowser of your choice and download the JARs etc. Just browse through the hierarchy (it looks like any Java packag hierarchy) until you find the artefact, then pick the right version and you're good.

For example version *3.6.6.Final* of *hibernate-core* from group *org.hibernate* you'd find here:

> > http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/3.6.6.Final/

Comment: +1 or use http://mvnrepository.com/ , it has a search interface and provides direct links to the artifacts.

Comment: The ibiblio links above were empty directories when I tried them.  Sean's link to mvnrepository.com worked well.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can setup a pom.xml to define your dependencies (the jars you want to copy). Then use the [dependency:copy-dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/copying-project-dependencies.html) goal to copy the jars to the desired location.

Answer (score 4):

Updated 2022 answer for command line - building on [Ivan Carcamo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13273628/ivan-carcamo)'s answer:

`wget [the link that Ivan Carcamo points to in his screenshot]`

[image]

Edit: This may download the thin jar for some repositories, so you may need to find a different link for the fat jar

Answer (score 2):

As of December 12, 2022 the easiest way to download all dependencies including the jar file itself is to go to this link:

https://jar-download.com/online-maven-download-tool.php

And simply paste the Maven XML to the page and click download. God bless the person who built jar-download.com. :-)

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to download a JAR from a Gitlab Maven private repository. The URL is appearing when running some Maven command so it's a bit hacky but it's working for me.

Like this:

```
wget --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: ${GITLAB_PRIVATE_TOKEN}" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/${GITLAB_PROJECT_ID}/packages/maven/${MAVEN_PACKAGE_NAME}/${MAVEN_VERSION}/${JAR_FILE}"
```

Where,

- GITLAB_PRIVATE_TOKEN is a Gitlab Token with right "api" (atm the others are not enough)

  - GITLAB_PROJECT_ID e.g. 1462237
  - MAVEN_PACKAGE_NAME e.g. com/bar/foo
  - MAVEN_VERSION e.g. 0.0.1
  - JAR_FILE e.g. foo-0.0.1.jar

Answer (score 1):

All the jars are available directly in the maven central repository. You don't have to use "maven" if all you want is the jar.

https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/

If the pom dependency is

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

You can download it from the corresponding directory structure by replacing the dots with forward slashses on the group id, artifact id, and version. I would navigate to the final folder to get the exact link of the jar.

https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/poi/poi/5.2.2/poi-5.2.2.jar

Answer (score 1):

This works for me, but it downloads only the latest version:

```bash
#! /bin/bash
set -eu
if [[ -z ${1:-} || -z ${2:-} ]]; then
  printf 'Usage: %s group artifact\n' "$(basename "$0")" >&2
  exit 1
fi
g="$1"
a="$2"
url='https://search.maven.org'
v="$(curl -s "$url/solrsearch/select?q=g:$g+AND+a:$a&core=gav&rows=20&wt=json" |
          jq -r '.response.docs[0].v')"
curl -s -L -o "$a-$v.jar" "$url/remotecontent?filepath=${g//.//}/$a/$v/$a-$v.jar"
```

You need `bash`, `curl` and `jq`.

Example:

```
./maven-download net.sf.saxon Saxon-HE
```

Downloads `Saxon-HE-11.4.jar` today (2022-12-23).

Answer (score 0):

**Use the below code snip**

```
result = subprocess.check_output('mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:get \
                                     -DgroupId=%s \
                                     -DartifactId=%s \
                                     -Dversion=%s \
                                     -Dtransitive=false \
                                     -DremoteRepositories={repos_string} \
                                     -Dpackaging=jar \
                                     -DoutputDirectory=%s' % (group_id,
                                                              artifact_id,
                                                              version_name,
                                                              des_path), shell=True)
    logger.info("success download jar: %s" % each_version)
except Exception as e:
    logger.error("Error in download jar : %s" % str(e))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this plugin](https://github.com/maven-download-plugin/maven-download-plugin):

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>com.googlecode.maven-download-plugin</groupId>
  <artifactId>download-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.0</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>generate-test-resources</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>wget</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <uri>http://example.com/foo.zip</uri>
        <unpack>true</unpack>
        <maxLockWaitTime>100</maxLockWaitTime>
        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/foo</outputDirectory>
        <md5>5b1f9712b75439446f2fe3d4e1339448</md5>
        <checkSignature>true</checkSignature>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```