# How to use Maven pom to download jar files only to a specific directory?

Tags: java, maven

Is there a way to download dependencies from a pom.xml file to a specified folder in java? I'm able to run maven command from java and I got download messages, but I don't know where maven stores these libraries? How can I download these dependencies to a specific folder?

Answer (score 130, accepted):

Take a look at maven's dependency plugin, specifically the 
[`copy-dependencies`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html) goal. The [usage section](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/copying-project-dependencies.html) describes how to do exactly what you want.

To do it from the command line just do:

```
$ mvn dependency:copy-dependencies -DoutputDirectory=OUTPUT_DIR
```

Add this to exclude the transitive or inner dependencies:

`-DexcludeTransitive=true`

Comment: I'm encountering a strange issue with this method, it downloaded a .pom file for the main dependency but for its subdependencies (the transitive dependencies) it downloaded the proper jars. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Note, on Windows, use `mvn dependency:copy-dependencies "-DoutputDirectory=OUTPUT_DIR"`

Answer (score 12):

As explained [here](https://www.hadoopexception.com/java/how-to-download-a-specific-maven-artifact-in-one-command-line/), you can use [maven-dependency-plugin:get](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/get-mojo.html) for this.

For example, if you want to download `org.apache.hive:hive-common:2.1.1` in your local folder, execute this:

```
mvn dependency:get -Ddest=./ -Dartifact=org.apache.hive:hive-common:2.1.1
```

If you want to download the latest `3.0.0-SNAPSHOT:tar.gz` version of `com.orientechnologies:orientdb-community-gremlin` from `https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots` snapshots repository, execute this:

```
mvn dependency:get -Ddest=./ -DremoteRepositories=sonatype-nexus-snapshots::::https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots -Dartifact=com.orientechnologies:orientdb-community-gremlin:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT:tar.gz
```

Comment: You can use `-Dartifact=org.apache.hive:hive-common:LASTEST` to get the latest version.

Comment: [WARNING] destination/dest parameter is deprecated: it will disappear in future version.

Answer (score 7):

Add something similar to the following to pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <outputDirectory>
            ${project.build.directory}
        </outputDirectory>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Then run `mvn clean dependency:copy-dependencies` to perform the copy.
Combine this with the [assembly plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) and you can package everything into a self contained archive for distribution.

Comment: I changed `${project.build.directory}` to `main\java\resources\libs` to build my local library. Thanks! Note: here my path is relative to the `usr.dir` (project root), but it can also be absolute, like `C:\Mydir`. Great!

Answer (score 1):

Maven stores all of these in it's local Maven2 repository.  By default, it will store them in your user home directory under a directory called repository.

You can use the maven-dependency-plugin's goal called copy to take all of your project's dependencies and put them in a folder.

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-mojo.html

Comment: Is there any other way in java to copy dependencies as I don't write the pom.xml I just run it?

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to this site: http://jar-download.com/online-maven-download-tool.php
2. Insert the Maven dependencies XML
3. Download the jar files as a ZIP.

Comment: I'd refrain from downloading .jars through a third (fourth?) party site, who knows what else they add or how they modify to the archives (malware)? sblundy gave a more straight forward answer.

Comment: Site is down and using external APIs