# How to install software in Maven?

Tags: java, maven, package, jodatime

So I'm trying to wrap my head around Maven. After installing it I now want to install JodaTime because it's a dependency for another project.

I know I can download it and do a `mvn clean install` from within the JodaTime dir. From my experience with other package managers such as apt I suspect there is also a way of installing new software without manually downloading and untarring though. I just tried `mvn install JodaTime`, but I get an error saying:

> Unknown lifecycle phase "JodaTime". You must specify a valid lifecycle
>   phase [etc. etc.]

So my question; is there a way to install software in Maven without manually downloading it?

Answer (score 2):

If your project needs joda-time artifact as a dependency, you don't need to install it, all you need is to specify a dependency:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
    <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

If you're trying to build `joda-time` yourself from source in case you wanted to modify the source of joda-time then you need to check out the source from https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time and run `mvn install` to install it to your local repository.

Answer (score 0):

Maven is not build to do that (like sudo apt install in linux). But the closest is this as far as I know

[dependency:get](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/get-mojo.html)  mvn dependency:get -DrepoUrl=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ \
                   -DgroupId=junit -DartifactId=junit -Dversion=4.8.2 \

[Check this also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7110114/how-to-simply-download-a-jar-using-maven)

Comment: Surprised to see the downvote!

Answer (score 0):

Usually it is enough to just define a dependency in your `pom.xml` and MAven will do the right thing:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
    <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
    <version>1.6</version>
   </dependency>
```

In some cases you might need to define additional repositories in your settings.xml, but usually that is all you have to do.