# How to force using a jar as an automatic module, without editing it?

Tags: java, maven, java-module

I created a **Java 13** project that uses the modular system, and want to use [LITIEngine](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/de.gurkenlabs/litiengine/0.4.18), a game library made with java 8.

After adding the dependency in Maven using :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>de.gurkenlabs</groupId>
    <artifactId>litiengine</artifactId>
    <version>0.4.18</version>
</dependency>
```

I was expecting to use it as an automatic module, in my `module-info.java`:

```
module com.myproject {
    require litiengine; // Error: Module litiengine not found.
}
```

Surprisingly enough, it doesn't seem to be an automatic module, so I [grabbed the jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7110114/how-to-simply-download-a-jar-using-maven) and ran the command `jar --file=litiengine-0.4.18.jar --describe-module`, and got this weird result:

```
java.xml.bind jar:file:///D:/WhereverMyJarIs/litiengine-0.4.18.jar/!module-info.class
exports javax.xml.bind
exports javax.xml.bind.annotation
exports javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters
exports javax.xml.bind.attachment
exports javax.xml.bind.helpers
exports javax.xml.bind.util
requires java.activation transitive
requires java.base mandated
requires java.desktop
requires java.logging
requires java.xml transitive
uses javax.xml.bind.JAXBContextFactory
```

So, I am supposed to use LITIEngine as `java.xml.bind`? It doesn't have anything to do with the library I want to use. This makes no sense!

I still tried to require it:

```
module com.myproject {
    requires java.xml.bind; // IntelliJ gives an error: Ambiguous module reference: java.xml.bind
}
```

Despite the error IntelliJ gives me, i tried to compile my project with Maven, containing a simple `HelloWorld.java` file:

```
package com.myproject;

import de.gurkenlabs.litiengine.Game;

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Game.init(args);
        Game.start();
    }
}
```

When running `mvn compile`, the compilation fails *(I set `maven.compiler.target` and `maven.compiler.source` to `13`)*:

```
Error:(3,21) java: package de.gurkenlabs.litiengine is not visible
```

At this point, I just tried to use my project as a nonmodular one, but still use Java 13, so i just deleted the `module-info.java`, and like that, it works. Great, but I lose the ability to use the module system, which i need to use in my project.

**I tried one last thing**, I used the LITIEngine jar i grabbed earlier, and removed the `module-info.class` file in it, by opening the jar file as an archive in 7-zip and deleting that file. Then I added it as a local dependency in maven with:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=./whereverItIs/litiengine-0.4.18.jar \
-DgroupId=com.myproject.jars -DartifactId=litiengine -Dversion=1 -Dpackaging=jar
```

And I added it as a dependency:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.myproject.jars</groupId>
   <artifactId>litiengine</artifactId>
   <version>1</version>
</dependency>
```

I could then use the library in my `module-info.java`

```
module com.myproject {
    require litiengine; // No errors this time!
}
```

**And then successfully build it and run it!**

So, this proves that this library can work with when imported as an automatic module, but this requires me to **edit the jar file and remove the `module-info.class`** in order to make it work, which is **very undesirable**, because this requires manual action everytime the library receives an update.

**The perfect solution** would be to be able to **ignore the `module-info.class` file contained inside the jar and make the module system threat it as an automatic module**, is there a way to do that?

Comment: Removing files from a downloaded artifact is a bad habit. If the package/class is not visible the authors have a good reason not to use such things. So in the end it sounds as if you are not using the intended interface...furthermore ignoring a `module-info` does not make sense cause the author have defined things in that...and an automatic module will not help here...Furthermore I don't understand your comment: `and got this weird result:`...? What have you expect?

Comment: I know that doing this is a bad habit, which is why i want to find a solution that doesn't need to remove files. 

And I did not expect this result, as it describes a `java.xml.base` module, which is weird, because it doesn't have anything to do with the library i want to use, LITIEngine. I would expect instead to have no module-info file inside the jar at all. I edited the post to make it clearer.

Comment: @khmarbaise The reason why the result is stated as weird could be because of the module name, which is the same as that of [JAXB module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48204141/replacements-for-deprecated-jpms-modules-with-java-ee-apis). That said, the `module-info.class` within this artifact seems to have no relation with the package structure or classes within it.

Comment: @jeuxjeux20 An ideal solution would be for the maintainer of the artifact to fix this error. It could be by updating and fixing the `module-info.java` class in the module or just removing it if not intended and declaring the entry in `MANIFEST.MF`. So, go ahead and report it to the maintainers.

Comment: @Naman I'll file an issue to the [github repo](https://github.com/gurkenlabs/litiengine), thanks!

Comment: Yes of course the solution could only be the original artifact being fixed...that's of course simply wrong...