# Maven cannot find local POM file for submodule

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to use a "common" module as a dependency in a separate module, both modules being submodules of one parent module. `mvn clean install` completes **successfully**, but trying to compile the module with the dependency fails as it doesn't know where to look for the POM or JAR files. This is in a javax project.

Parent pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>project</groupId>
  <artifactId>quotations</artifactId>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <name>quotations</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <modules>
    <module>common</module>
    <module>service1</module>
  </modules>
</project>
```

common pom

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>service-ad</groupId>
    <artifactId>common</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <archive>
                                <manifest>
                                    <mainClass>${main.class}</mainClass>
                                </manifest>
                            </archive>
                            <descriptorRefs>
                                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                            </descriptorRefs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

service1 pom

```
 <project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>service-ad</groupId>
    <artifactId>service1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <properties>
        <main.class>service.core.Quoter</main.class>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

     <dependencies>
          <dependency>
           <groupId>service-ad</groupId>
           <artifactId>common</artifactId>
           <version>1.0</version>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
             <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
             <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
             <version>2.3.1</version>
         </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-ri</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.jws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr181-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-MR1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.jmdns</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmdns</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
     </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>${main.class}</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <archive>
                                <manifest>
                                    <mainClass>${main.class}</mainClass>
                                </manifest>
                            </archive>
                            <descriptorRefs>
                                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                            </descriptorRefs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

execution output:

```
 ──── ─ mvn compile exec:java -pl service1 -U
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djava.util.prefs.userRoot=/home/conor/.config/java
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------< service-ad:service1>-------------------------
[INFO] Building service1 0.0.1
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/service-ad/common/1.0/common-1.0.pom
[WARNING] The POM for service-ad:common:jar:1.0 is missing, no dependency information available
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/service-ad/common/1.0/common-1.0.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.347 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-10-03T15:22:12+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project service1: Could not resolve dependencies for project service-ad:service1:jar:1.0: Could not find artifact service-ad:common:jar:1.0 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

Directory structure:

```
project -
        |- pom.xml
        |- common -
                  |- pom.xml
                  |- src folder
                  |- target folder
        |-service1-
                  |- pom.xml
                  |- src folder
                  |- target folder
```

Comment: Can you show the directory structure and where you start the build from ?

Comment: #1 after the `mvn clean install`, and before the exec, try to determinate if common jar is locally installed: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7110499/3957754 #2 for development is easy to use modules but for real environment in enterprises or with a devops flow, each jar must be built separately. Are you open to that advice?

Comment: @JRichardsz The jar does exist in `project/common/target/common-1.0.jar` if thats what you mean.

Comment: @khmarbaise edited to add directory structure

Comment: In which directory have you started Maven? Hopefully `project`?

Comment: yes, running the project in the root project dir @khmarbaise

Comment: #1 No matter what are you using, if this is the error `Could not find artifact service-ad:common:jar:1.0` it means that your jar does not exist on local nor remote. Try to determinate if common jar is locally installed: stackoverflow.com/a/7110499/3957754 #2 Are we talking of just two jars (service who depends of common) or a third app who needs the service? #3 Are you open to a solution to your issue without parent usage?

Comment: @JRichardsz #1: I got a build failure from the dependency:get command, however I also got a build failed for modules I know I have installed, e.g. junit. #2: At the moment just a service that relies on common, two jars. #3: Unfortunately im not able to go without a parent module

Comment: mmm that is another problem. If common is the deepest dependency, mvn clean install should work. Try to fix it and share us the result. `dependency:get` work on any public  or local (previous install) dependency

Comment: You have another error. I copy pasted your poms and **mvn clean install** works as expected https://i.ibb.co/XyxxYr0/maven-parent-reactor-result.png Also the **dependency:get** works after the previous install https://i.ibb.co/84GFW27/maven-dependency-get-result.png

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out! So my maven target folders were owned by `root` for reasons unknown, and to run `mvn clean install` I had to run as sudo to avoid permission denied errors. I wasn't running the execution with sudo so the jars weren't found.

I've since changed ownership of the target files to let me proceed without sudo - happy days.