# How to resolve maven dependency explicitly from command line arguments?

Tags: maven, command-line, dependencies, properties, command-line-interface

I have a project A which depends on artifact B. I made some hack on B, and want to see it in A. So I don't want A to use the version in my local repository, instead, I want A to use my hacked version of B.

I'm looking for a solution that can specify my-hacked-B.jar as dependency of A, like this:

```
cd A && mvn package -Ddependency.org.groupB.B.jar.path=path/to/my-hacked-B.jar
```

Is it possible, or I have to install the modified B in my local repository?

Comment: You can do this from command line:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1776496/a-simple-command-line-to-download-a-remote-maven2-artifact-to-the-local-reposito

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to resolve dependency from command line, but there is a way to let maven resolve dependency externally.

I created a temporal wrapper pom.xml which aggregates the two projects. It works, without install anything into local repository.

The only problem is that I am unable to use absolute path in `<module/>`.

See http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Aggregation

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it on the command line, but you can [set the dependency scope to `system`](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#System_Dependencies) in the pom.xml and provide a path to the dependency.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.groupB</groupId>
  <artifactId>B</artifactId>
  <version>2.0</version>
  <scope>system</scope>
  <systemPath>${project.basedir}/path/to/hacked-B.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks. But I don't want my pom.xml to be dirty.

Comment: @user955091 I thought so, but unfortunately that's the only way that I know of.

Answer (score 1):

A little bit late :) You can do it with properties:

```
<properties>
    <org.groupB.B.scope>compile</org.groupB.B.scope>
    <org.groupB.B.path></org.groupB.B.path>
</properties>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.groupB</groupId>
    <artifactId>B</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
    <scope>${org.groupB.B.scope}</scope>
    <systemPath>${org.groupB.B.path}</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

and then:

```
mvn package -Dorg.groupB.B.scope=system -Dorg.groupB.B.path=path/to/my-hacked-B.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

You could `mvn clean install` your hacked version into your local maven repo, over the version you downloaded from the 'net.  You'd need to make sure that project B's pom reflects the version you are depending on and *not* a snapshot version. (Or, to put it more generally: The version of project B that you `mvn clean install` must match the version you require in project A. Whether you edit A's pom or B's pom doesn't matter.)