# How to install maven artifact directly into repo

Tags: maven, groovy, groovy-grape

In grape there is a nice way to download any artifact to repo directly, just calling something like

```
grape install org.apache.derby derby 10.5.3.0
```

As far as I understand, `maven install:install` [goal](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/usage.html) requires `pom.xml` file, and `maven install:install-file` requires local file which you are pointing to and which you actually want to place in local repo.

Is there is any way to install any artifact to maven repo directly, without creating maven project and declaring dependency in pom.xml?

**UPD:**  I guess the search [is over](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1776496/a-simple-command-line-to-download-a-remote-maven2-artifact-to-the-local-reposito).  We should use `dependency:get` goal.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? What's wrong with declaring it as a dependency when you need it and Maven will download it for you?

Comment: @nwinkler - I've expected this question)  I want exactly the same thing as in grape just because I'm trying to use maven repo with grape as well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [A simple command line to download a remote maven2 artifact to the local repository?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1776496/a-simple-command-line-to-download-a-remote-maven2-artifact-to-the-local-reposito)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A simple command line to download a remote maven2 artifact to the local repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1776496/a-simple-command-line-to-download-a-remote-maven2-artifact-to-the-local-reposito)

Comment: @M.Justin since it's a literally 10 years old question I don't remember exactly the context but since then yep, I've learnt how to install specific maven dependency from command line )