# deploying multiple wars using maven- jetty, tomcat?

Tags: java, web-applications, maven, jetty

I want to deploy multiple webapps and run either the  maven jetty plugin or tomcat plugin. 
But I can't seem to get them to work. 
My main aim is to start the server will all the webapps since they are dependent on each other. 
How do I achieve this?
I tried with the maven jetty plugin- created a separate project with multiple contextHandlers

```xml
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>    
        <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>8.1.2.v20120308</version>
        <configuration>
            <contextHandlers>
                <contextHandler implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
                    <contextPath>/data-emulator</contextPath>
                    <resourceBase>${basedir}/../data-emulator/target/</resourceBase>

                </contextHandler>

                <contextHandler implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
                    <contextPath>/service</contextPath>
                    <resourceBase>${basedir}/../service/target/</resourceBase>

                </contextHandler>

                <contextHandler implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
                    <contextPath>/client</contextPath>
                    <resourceBase>${basedir}/../client/target/</resourceBase>

                </contextHandler>
            </contextHandlers>
            <connector implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector"> 
                <port>8080</port>
                <maxIdleTime>60000</maxIdleTime>
            </connector>

        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10567699/getting-http-500-when-running-servlet-in-jetty/10609507#10609507 , you want to setup multiple instances or deploy more wars on the same instance?

Answer (score 2):

your **resourceBase** parameter is incorrect. the **target** folder doesnt contain your webpages and the WEB-INF folder (unless you have special post-build tasks that copies the output files over).

you should use the **war** parameter instead. example below:

```
<contextHandler implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
    <contextPath>/data-emulator</contextPath>
    <war>${basedir}/../data-emulator/target/data-emulator.war</war>    
</contextHandler>
```

Comment: > it is essential that you use an org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext instance rather than a standard org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext instance. Only the former will allow the webapp to function correctly in the maven environment.