# EOF / Invalid function argument (errno:4022) with Jetty 9

Tags: java, jetty, nio, jetty-9

Couldnt find whether there is any configuration for static content. Its not downloading the js file, I hope it because of larger in size when compare with others.

[image]

Jetty version : 9.2.10 
OS : HP Nonstop

I can see the following errors in jetty debug

```
DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher - write exception
org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException: null
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint.flush(ChannelEndPoint.java:192) ~[jetty-io-9.2.10.v20150310.jar:9.2.10.v20150310]
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher.flush(WriteFlusher.java:408) ~[jetty-io-9.2.10.v20150310.jar:9.2.10.v20150310]
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher.write(WriteFlusher.java:302) ~[jetty-io-9.2.10.v20150310.jar:9.2.10.v20150310]
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractEndPoint.write(AbstractEndPoint.java:129) ~[jetty-io-9.2.10.v20150310.jar:9.2.10.v20150310]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$SendCallback.process(HttpConnection.java:676) ~[jetty-server-9.2.10.v20150310.jar:9.2.10.v20150310]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.IteratingCallback.processing(IteratingCallback.java:246) ~[jetty-util-9.2.10.v20150310.jar:9.2.10.v20150310]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.IteratingCallback.iterate(IteratingCallback.java:208) ~[jetty-util-9.2.10.v20150310.jar:9.2.10.v20150310]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.send(HttpConnection.java:471) ~[jetty-server-9.2.10.v20150310.jar:9.2.10.v20150310]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.sendResponse(HttpChannel.java:763) ~[jetty-server-9.2.10.v20150310.jar:9.2.10.v20150310]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.write(HttpChannel.java:801) ~[jetty-server-9.2.10.v20150310.jar:9.2.10.v20150310]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:142) ~[jetty-server-9.2.10.v20150310.jar:9.2.10.v20150310]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.sendContent(HttpOutput.java:583) ~[jetty-server-9.2.10.v20150310.jar:9.2.10.v20150310]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.sendContent(HttpOutput.java:669) ~[jetty-server-9.2.10.v20150310.jar:9.2.10.v20150310]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.sendContent(HttpOutput.java:571) ~[jetty-server-9.2.10.v20150310.jar:9.2.10.v20150310]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet.sendData(DefaultServlet.java:955) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.10.v20150310.jar:9.2.10.v20150310]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet.doGet(DefaultServlet.java:533) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.10.v20150310.jar:9.2.10.v20150310]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687) ~[servlet-api-3.1.jar:3.1.0]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) ~[servlet-api-3.1.jar:3.1.0]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:808) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.10.v20150310.jar:9.2.10.v20150310]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:587) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.10.v20150310.jar:9.2.10.v20150310]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143) ~[jetty-server-9.2.10.v20150310.jar:9.2.10.v20150310]
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577) ~[jetty-security-9.2.10.v20150310.jar:9.2.10.v20150310]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223) ~[jetty-server-9.2.10.v20150310.jar:9.2.10.v20150310]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127) ~[jetty-server-9.2.10.v20150310.jar:9.2.10.v20150310]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.10.v20150310.jar:9.2.10.v20150310]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185) ~[jetty-server-9.2.10.v20150310.jar:9.2.10.v20150310]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061) ~[jetty-server-9.2.10.v20150310.jar:9.2.10.v20150310]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141) ~[jetty-server-9.2.10.v20150310.jar:9.2.10.v20150310]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215) ~[jetty-server-9.2.10.v20150310.jar:9.2.10.v20150310]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:110) ~[jetty-server-9.2.10.v20150310.jar:9.2.10.v20150310]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97) ~[jetty-server-9.2.10.v20150310.jar:9.2.10.v20150310]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:497) ~[jetty-server-9.2.10.v20150310.jar:9.2.10.v20150310]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310) ~[jetty-server-9.2.10.v20150310.jar:9.2.10.v20150310]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257) ~[jetty-server-9.2.10.v20150310.jar:9.2.10.v20150310]
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540) ~[jetty-io-9.2.10.v20150310.jar:9.2.10.v20150310]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635) ~[jetty-util-9.2.10.v20150310.jar:9.2.10.v20150310]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555) ~[jetty-util-9.2.10.v20150310.jar:9.2.10.v20150310]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) ~[na:1.7.0_25]

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Invalid function argument (errno:4022)
at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.writev0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.writev(SocketDispatcher.java:51) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:149) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:512) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint.flush(ChannelEndPoint.java:172) ~[jetty-io-9.2.10.v20150310.jar:9.2.10.v20150310]
... 37 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Do you mean uploading? Browser is downloading.

Comment: @MariuszS its when downloading http://localhost:8080/myapp/appmin.js

Answer (score 1):

You mean Jetty is uploading or sending the content, not downloading.
That much is evident from your stacktrace.

The main problem you are having is that the connection is terminated with an EOF when attempting to flush out that connection.

However, the more fundamental problem you are having `java.io.IOException: Invalid function argument (errno:4022)` isn't something that Jetty can fix or work around.  This is an OS level error indicating either an inability to use the file descriptor to the network connection, or a file system error indicating an inability to use the file descriptor to access the file on disk.

Either way you should check your OS, the filesystem, the health of the WAR file, the filesystem temp directory, and also consider an upgrade of your Java JVM ([1.7.0_25 expired back in Nov 15, 2013](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/7u25-relnotes-1955741.html))

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer. jvm version is customer scope. Os is actually HP nonstop server (tandem). The same code works in jetty8 problem appears when I upgrade to jetty9. Jetty8 I use BIO connector but jetty9 seems only NIO.

Comment: All BIO connectors have been dropped, as Java and the Servlet spec is moving towards a all async/nio infrastructure.

Comment: Note, the filesystem and/or that file could also be having problems that cause this particular error.