# Executing a JAR file straight from a Maven repository

Tags: java, maven, executable-jar, execution

Suppose that we have a Java *application*, rather than a library, which is available through Maven central. For example, one such project is [jol](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jol/), which has its corresponding CLI interface [in Maven central](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjdk.jol/jol-cli).

As far as I can tell, the main difference from a library is that the corresponding JAR file contains a class with an appropriate `main()` method and, optionally, a related `Main-Class:` header in the JAR manifest. If such an artifact is used as a dependency on a project, Maven will happily download the JAR file to the local repository along with its dependencies, as it does for any other artifact.

*Is it possible to use Maven to execute such an application directly, without setting up a Maven project?*

The [`exec:java` plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/java-mojo.html) works nicely for local projects by setting up the JVM classpath so that dependencies are available. The user does not have to worry about JAR or `.class` file locations and such. Unfortunately, from what I can tell, it also requires an enclosing Maven project, so it cannot be used from an arbitrary command line prompt.

Comment: I'd probably just wrap up something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1776496/a-simple-command-line-to-download-a-remote-maven2-artifact-to-the-local-reposito with a shell script that then executes the downloaded artifact. Or write a simple program that talks Maven repo and can fetch an artifact and skip Maven altogether.

Comment: @DaveNewton: Getting the JAR file is not the only issue. `exec:java`, for example, will set up the JVM classpath so that dependencies are available. *That* is what I am after...

Comment: You can get the jar's dependencies programmatically and do the same thing, though. In any case, if you have Maven installed, then creating an ad-hoc project with your top-level dependency is a pretty small POM file. Why can't you just create the project on-the-fly? What's the issue?

Comment: @DaveNewton: I suppose the main issue is that I am not fond of reinventing the wheel, if a solution already exists. Also, doing it *right* with a script is not quite that simple (or that portable, for that matter)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, Maven will not do what you are asking for. It is a build tool, intended to build a Java project based on it's pom.xml file which describes the project.

So, you can't run a maven build without a pom.xml file.
And if you have a pom.xml, then by definition, you have 'set up a Maven project'.

As @DaveNewton says, you should be able to set up a very small pom.xml with the dependency for the jar file in question, and the exec-maven plugin. I'm afraid that it's just not going to get any simpler than that.

Answer (score 2):

A hacky solution working with Maven 3 would be to use the Maven Dependency Plugin in combination with the Maven Help Plugin to resolve the local repository path:

```
# Download JAR from Maven repo
mvn dependency:get -DremoteRepositories=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ \
                   -DgroupId=some.group.id \
                   -DartifactId=some-artifact-cli \
                   -Dversion=1.0.0 \
                   -Dtransitive=false

# Resolve local repository path
MVN_REPO=$(mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=settings.localRepository -q -DforceStdout)

# Execute JAR from the local repository
java -jar $MVN_REPO/some/group/id/some-artifact-cli/1.0.0/some-artifact-cli-1.0.0.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

You can now use `ktx` to execute a jar file from it's maven coordinates.

For example:

```
ktx run com.github.ricksbrown:cowsay:1.1.0 hello
```

Usage is explained on project's repo :
https://github.com/mpetuska/ktx