# how do I download a .war file from maven central?

Tags: java, maven, maven-central

I have the following instructions:

`Download the latest jetty-console.war from Maven Central (download the jetty-console.war artifact).`

So I go to the link, here:  http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22killbill-profiles-killbill%22

But how do I download using a command line (I am SSH'ing into my server).

Note:  I have read this link, but I don't seem to be able to download the plugin based on the instructions:

[A simple command line to download a remote maven2 artifact to the local repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1776496/a-simple-command-line-to-download-a-remote-maven2-artifact-to-the-local-reposito)

In part, I cannot tell what the repo URL should be if I use it, and the command doesn't appear to download the plugin.

Comment: `man wget` could probably help

Comment: Are you actively using Maven?

Comment: Okay, I played around with `wget` --- I thought I would need to do something like using `maven` to download it.

Comment: I get the following error: `java -jar killbill-*-jetty-console.war =>
Error: Unable to access jarfile killbill-*-jetty-console.war`

Answer (score 1):

Here are some generic steps:

1. Figure out what the direct link to the file is, in your example it's [this link](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/kill-bill/billing/killbill-profiles-killbill/0.12.1/killbill-profiles-killbill-0.12.1.war) for the war
2. Use some command line tool to download the file

example with [wget](http://linux.die.net/man/1/wget):

```
wget 'http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/kill-bill/billing/killbill-profiles-killbill/0.12.1/killbill-profiles-killbill-0.12.1.war'
```

*Another possibility would be to [rsync](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) or [scp](http://linux.die.net/man/1/scp) the war from your machine*

Comment: I had done `wget` but then when, per the instructions, I typed `java -jar killbill-*-jetty-console.war` it says it could not find it...so I wasn't sure if it was working.

Comment: look at the name of the war, also note that war are usually not runnable as jar

Comment: @Angela, A .war is not a jar file, it's a web application archive. You need to deploy it to a server in order to make it work.